# Difference between `Writes[MyClass]` and `Writes[MyClass.type]`?

Tags: json, scala, types, playframework

I have a function that takes a `Writes[Class.type]` as an argument and when I pass it it says that the actual passed argument is `Writes[Class]` and refuses to compile.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class` refers to a type named `Class`. `Class.type` refers to the type of the object named `Class`.

Consider this code as an example:

```
class Foo {
  val x = 42
}
object Foo {
  val y = 23
}

def f(foo: Foo) {
  println(foo.x)
  // The next line wouldn't work because the Foo class does not have a member y:
  // println(foo.y)
}

def g(foo: Foo.type) {
  println(foo.y)
  // The next line wouldn't work because the Foo object does not have a member x:
  println(foo.x)
}

val foo1 = new Foo
val foo2 = new Foo
f(foo1)
f(foo2)
// Does not work because the object Foo is not an instance of the class Foo:
// f(Foo)

g(Foo)
// Does not work because g only accepts the object Foo:
// g(foo1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was missing.